# How to default simulated metrics in xcode 6.3 interface builder storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I add a new view controller to a storyboard in Xcode 6.3 it defaults to inferred in the simulated metrics.

I prefer setting the size to 3"5 inch to allow me to see more objects.

Is there anyway to set this as the default, rather than going and changing the size metric.

In general it would be handy to be able to set a preference. I know I can just duplicate and change with ⌘D but that is not a method I like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change Storyboard metrics, so that Every new controlled added will become in the same size you have choiced.

By default the xCode will give you **Base metrics**, look like [THIS](http://postimg.org/image/nqksfeyul/)

You can change your metrics like [Iphone Portrait](http://postimg.org/image/heugdjjt9/)

Please provide your feedback, if this is not the case.

HTH, Enjoye !!

Comment: Be very wary of adding an object when in a particular size class. I was using compact/compact and could not understand why subview were not showing. It is safest to stick to any/any